# How to Only changed data from access database

Tags: c#

Hi I have a database to which new data is added every minute. I have a C# datagrid in winform which displays this db table. We refresh this datagrid every 5 minutes. Is there a way I show only the new added data and not the older ones

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thropugh adding `timestamp` in your database.

By this you can set the limit of timestamp means , you will have to query the database to show only last 5 minutes time stamp's `update` in your `grid`.

Can also set the `limit` in query if its needed to limit the data in `gridview`.

This you can do in `ASP.net` as well as `winforms`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by filtering the records `descending` with the newly generated uniqueId and also get the specific data with some limit (1 -10 the limit can be defined by you).